# Como fazer um update no banco de dados em várias tabelas relacionadas com codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Estou tentando fazer um update com codeigniter em duas tabelas relacionadas, mas não estou conseguindo.

Estou usando o seguinte código.

```
    $this->db->set('p.page', $dados['page']);
    $this->db->set('c.title_map', $dados['title_map']);
    $this->db->where('p.id', $idpage);
    $this->db->where('c.pages_id', $idpage);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $this->db->update('pages as p, customers as c', $dados, $condicao);
```

E estou obtendo o seguinte erro.

```
    Ocorreu um erro de banco de dados

    Error Number: 1146
    Table 'newaircobraz.pages as p, customers' doesn't exist

    UPDATE `pages as p, customers` as `c` SET `p`.`page` = 'OK Customers', `c`.`title_map` = 'OK Click the red dots to view customers in each country.', `id` = 'EN', `page` = 'OK Customers', `title_map` = 'OK Click the red dots to view customers in each country.' WHERE `p`.`id` = '3' AND `c`.`pages_id` = '3' AND `id` = 'EN' LIMIT 1

    Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/aircobraz/application/models/paginas_model.php
    Line Number: 75
```

Comment: Segundo a mensagem de erro, essa tabela 'page as p, customers as c' não existe. Verifique a existência da mesma para garantir que a query funcione corretamente.

Answer (score 2):

Faça um update de cada vez.

```
$this->db->update('pages',$dados,$condicao);

$this->db->update('customers',$dados,$condicao);
```